# ¿Cómo bloquear una Base de Datos en SQL Server durante la reducción de espacio?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una consulta con respecto a este script para reducir una base de datos por "ARCHIVOS". Lo que he hecho es generar el script con el *"SQL Server Management Studio 2008"*. He elegido la opción: *"Reorganizar páginas antes de liberar espacio no utilizado"* y he puesto el valor de 1MB para asegurarme que se libere lo máximo de espacio posible.

Mi duda es si hay más opciones que agregar, como por ejemplo tipo para: *"Bloquear la base de datos durante la reducción"*.

```
USE [BaseReduccion]
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'BaseReduccion' , 1)
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'BaseReduccion_log' , 1)
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que lo mejor es dejar la base en modo "Usuario único" mientras ejecutas el SHRINK

```
ALTER DATABASE BaseReduccion
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
-- Luego al finalizar
ALTER DATABASE BaseReduccion SET MULTI_USER
```

Con esto solo tu processo de SHRINK va a tener acceso total a la base, lo usuarios que intenten acceder a la base recibirán un error de conexión.

Comment: Al ponerlo en modo `READ ONLY`, ¿no se estarían bloqueando todas escrituras a la base de datos incluyendo el `SHRINK`?

Comment: Gracias @Flxtr, efectivamente es lo que dices, ahora edito la respuesta, estoy acostumbrado a poner en READ_ONLY al hacer un BACKUP

Comment: Gracias, ¿Esa es la instrucción correcta entonces?. No sé si sea posible hacer esta pregunta, pero no entiendo por que el archivo de registros (log) en vez de decrecer, se incrementa más y no hay forma de reducirlo.

Comment: El SHRINK no necesariamente va a lograr decrecer el LOG todo depende de como se organicen internamente los registros en el Log,

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ¿Y hay alguna forma de contrarestar (reducir) ese inconveniente?

Comment: en pocas palabras BACKUP LOG, te recomiendo [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56628/how-do-you-clear-the-sql-server-transaction-log) pregunta en SO